# How to call codeiginiter controller from a javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to change my routing page in codeiginiter. how can i change my default controller

Someone already do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Elaborate more. What have you tried yet?

Comment: The title and content dont match???

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you well, you wanted to change your default controller.

You can do it in `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'; // Change welcome with your default controller class,
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `application/config` folder and open `routes.php` files and change this line :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "name_of_your_controller";
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling Ajax Api in your JavaScript file, you can call controller

for these you can follow below steps -

1. first include jQuery in your CodeIgniter project.
2. Now, Add Ajax call in javascript file

```js
$.ajax({
                url: "users/get_client_details",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"userId": id},
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.status === "false") {
                        alert("Please Enter Correct id.");
                    }
                }
            });
```

3. Add routes path in routes.php

$route['users/get_client_details'] = 'users/fetch_client_details';

Now you can access your controller from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have set up a route for the ajax request. Something like this:

```
$route['admin/search/(:any)'] = 'admin_controller/admin/do_search/$1';
```

Then my ajax request would look like this:
AJAX Request

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
data : 'your data',
url : '<?php array('controller'=>'abc','action'=>'you function')?>',
success :   function(data){
           alert(success)
}
});
```